# How do I use the different shades of a color swatch in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, material-design, flutter

In the default Flutter application code, I tried to change the following code

from:

```
primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey
```

to:

```
primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey[500]
```

but this throws an error:

```
 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4512): The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
I/flutter ( 4512): type 'Color' is not a subtype of type 'MaterialColor' of 'primarySwatch' where
I/flutter ( 4512):   Color is from dart:ui
I/flutter ( 4512):   MaterialColor is from package:flutter/src/material/colors.dart
I/flutter ( 4512):   int is from dart:core
I/flutter ( 4512): 
I/flutter ( 4512): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 4512): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 4512): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 4512):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new
I/flutter ( 4512): 
I/flutter ( 4512): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 4512): #0      new ThemeData (package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart:78:19)
I/flutter ( 4512): #1      MyApp.build (/data/user/0/com.hackathon.gunbanana/cache/gun_bananaEMVSSI/gun_banana/lib/main.dart:11:18)
I/flutter ( 4512): #2      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3678:28)
I/flutter ( 4512): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3625:15)
I/flutter ( 4512): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
I/flutter ( 4512): #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
I/flutter ( 4512): #6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
I/flutter ( 4512): #7      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
I/flutter ( 4512): #8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
I/flutter ( 4512): #9      RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:852:16)
I/flutter ( 4512): #10     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:823:5)
I/flutter ( 4512): #11     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:769:17)
I/flutter ( 4512): #12     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2205:19)
I/flutter ( 4512): #13     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:768:13)
I/flutter ( 4512): #14     BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:657:7)
I/flutter ( 4512): #15     runApp (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:699:7)
I/flutter ( 4512): #16     main (/data/user/0/com.hackathon.gunbanana/cache/gun_bananaEMVSSI/gun_banana/lib/main.dart:3:16)
I/flutter ( 4512): #17     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:279)
I/flutter ( 4512): #18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165)
I/flutter ( 4512): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

[image: Message on the mobile]

How do I use shades?

Comment: Similar error occurred for me. I was using `Colors.black` as the swatch color. However as soon as I changed it to `Colors.blue` it worked. It also worked for some other colors, but not `Colors.black`. And also, `swatch` has to be the base color not the varitions of it, because that is what `swatches` are meant for; generate all variations of a Base color. So whatever base color you provide to a `swatch` it has to be one of the valid values of `MaterialColor` else it crashes.

Answer (score 33):

**TLDR**

Do

```
ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.lime),
```

Don't

```
ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.lime.shade700),
```

---

primarySwatch is not *one* color. It's all the possible material shades.

If you look into `ThemeData`'s doc it says :

> The primary color palette (the [primarySwatch]), chosen from
>   one of the swatches defined by the material design spec. This
>   should be one of the maps from the [Colors] class that do not
>   have "accent" in their name.

This implies that when needed the material component will use primary[500] but may also use other shades !

In fact, `primarySwatch` is a shortcut to set a bunch of different colors :

- primaryColor
- primaryColorLight/Dark
- accentColor
- ...

But you can override them separatly depending on your needs, with a `Color` (and not the `MaterialColor` that primarySwatch requires)

Comment: I'm not comfortable with this answer. In my code I've tried

      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lime.shade700,

      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lime[700],

and receive the same error messages as OP. Would you be more specific and supply an example?

Comment: You need to do `primarySwatch: Colors.lime` instead of `Colors.line.whatever`

Comment: I found that primarySwatch requires a different format than backgroundColor. So the confusion was on my part. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Great answer. I was using my own hex colors wrapped into a color object for all kinds of primary colors, but still was having the swatch property turned on. Now I comment it out, the app works... yippee!!!

Comment: I think you should include examples on how to use different shades. For example, how many colors should be defined in a swatch and how to actually define it in code.

Answer (score 21):

In main.dart file make your custom color outside of MyApp class as below :

```
Map<int, Color> color = {
50: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .1),
100: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .2),
200: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .3),
300: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .4),
400: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .5),
500: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .6),
600: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .7),
700: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .8),
800: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, .9),
900: Color.fromRGBO(255, 92, 87, 1),
};

MaterialColor colorCustom = MaterialColor(0xFFFF5C57, color);
```

And then just set it to your primarySwatch property inside ThemeData like below

```
primarySwatch: colorCustom,
```

Comment: what we supposed to do with the accent color map (A100-A700)?