# EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY in flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When i am trying to run my own flutter app in android studio it gives error like this

**This is my app screenshot:**

[image]

**This is my logcat:**

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the logcat errors. It is not ideal to post screenshots of the errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319333/how-do-i-use-the-different-shades-of-a-color-swatch-in-flutter/49320787#49320787

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Colors.black` is a single color, but `primarySwatch` expects a palette of multiple colors.  If you look at the documentation for [Colors](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Colors-class.html), the different built in palettes are shown.  For example, Colors.blue is a blue palette, and can be passed to `primarySwatch`.

```
new MaterialApp(theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue))
```

Answer (score 0):

see your space in single quotation, you should write
like this : var first = ['answer':'black','white',...];